# Using urllib.request.urlopen returns blank but from Chrome I can see there is data in Response

Tags: python

It is my first question and appreciate that you could provide some hints to me.

I am developing a spider using python to crawl the odds entry from a website. In that website, there is a onclick event to pop up a window to show the change of odds. I checked from Chrome that it links to a url, "http://odds.500.com/fenxi1/inc/yazhiajax.php?fid=554629&id=3&t=" + str(t) + "&r=1"
Here t is a Javascript (new Date).getTime(). I can see the odds change from Chrome's preview and response. However, when I run below code to fetch the data. It shows blank. And when I navigate to the url through Chrome, it shows blank either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7TuP.jpg)

```
import datetime
import re
import urllib.request
import lottery
import gzip
import time

# getTime simulates Javascript getTime function
def getTime():
    return int(time.time() * 1000)

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36'"
referer = "http://odds.500.com/fenxi/yazhi-554629.shtml"
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, 'Referer': referer}

t = getTime()
url_str = "http://odds.500.com/fenxi1/inc/yazhiajax.php?fid=554629&id=3&t=" + str(t) + "&r=1"
print(url_str)
req = urllib.request.Request(url_str, headers = headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP request does not consist only of URL. You can see in Chrome's Developer tools (ctrl+shift+I) all requests and responses in Network tab.

I opened your referer URL (http://odds.500.com/fenxi/yazhi-554629.shtml) in chrome and clicked one of the items in "盘" column. I believe that is what you are trying to mimic. It sent a request with many cookies. That is probably you problem.

You should probably make your crawler open the first URL, gather all the cookies and then make the second requset with the cookies.

That might be a challenge though, depending on what you have to do to gather the cookies.

Note also that when you the response is not a complete HTML document - it is a JSON list of HTML segments.

**EDIT: Found the Answer**

I had to check the headers again. If you just add this header, you will get a response: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. So:

```
url = 'http://odds.500.com/fenxi1/inc/yazhiajax.php?fid=554629&id=3&t=1449930953112&r=1'
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)).read()
```

It returns some binary data... I'll leave that to you to decode. Hint: respnse headers say `Content-Encoding:gzip`, so it's zipped...

Comment: yes, I suspected it is related to json. In fact, the onclick event on that column invokes getJson. When I checked the Chrome, it points to one  URL and there is response for that URL. However, if I copy the url and paste it to a new window, it only shows a blank page to me.

Comment: Thanks zvone. Yes, I've checked the header again last night and found it is xmlhttprequest. I add X_Requested_With = "XMLHttpRequest" to my headers and add data = response.json(), after that, I got the data finally. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using proper headers should resolve the issue. Try checking the headers below:

```
headers = {
                        'Host': "twitter.com",
                        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)",
                        'Accept': "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                        'Accept-Language': "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
                        'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
                        'Referer': url,
                        'Connection': "keep-alive"
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather use [urllib3](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/).

To get a page using urllib3:

```
   import urllib3
   url = http://odds.500.com/fenxi1/inc/yazhiajax.php?fid=554629&id=3&t=" + str(t) + "&r=1"
   http = urllib3.PoolManager()
   page = http.request('GET',url)
```

There you have your page.

Comment: it shows 404 page not found error...if I use urllib3